# How can I speed up search/browse/filter with 10 M products?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, search, caching, indexing

**Background:**

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET 4 on Windows 2008

I have one table with about 10 million rows of products that I make available online for users to browse -- not search. Each of the 10 million products have extra attributes -- like categories -- that I keep in lookup tables -- there are three or four lookup tables.

**Problem**

When someone browses and starts using filters (shipping location, price, quality, brand), I need to join the tables, apply all the filters, and return the results. It's very slow and I want to make it faster. Sometimes users will apply a very broad filter, resulting in 800,000 results, and though I only return the first 10 of those for browsing, I still need to run the query for the full 800,000.

**What I've Tried Already**

I've joined all the information from the various tables into one physical table and then created a covering index for the table.

The queries are much faster, but there is a good bit of maintenance I have to do on the table behind the scenes with jobs to make sure if something goes out of stock I take it out within a reasonable time frame (5 mins or so).

I don't use materialized/indexed views b/c I've got aggregates in the results which SQL Server doesn't seem to like.

**Question**

How can I speed up browse results beyond the indexing and table optimization that I've already done? I'm not doing any full-text searches -- I'm filtering with exact parameters.

**Possible Solutions I've Thought Of**

Large caching solution -- AppFabric or MemCached. I'm know next to nothign about these and don't know they are appropriate.

Small caching solution -- Maybe leveraging ASP.NET caching -- but every person is going to apply different filters so I'm not sure how much this will give me.

SSDs -- as a larger-scale solution I've thought about getting SSDs but that will be down the road

CDN -- I don't think a CDN will help b/c the bottleneck here is my database's search capabilities, not the bandwidth/distance to the requester.

Comment: Why do you perform the full query if you only return 10 results?

Comment: Where exactly is the lackluster performance? is it obtaining the results based on filters? is it returning the 800,000 results and only rendering 10? is it rending the results? are you returning all 800,000 and only rendering 10? You could use server side paging to help too.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125

Comment: I perform the full query b/c I need to populate the new filters and the number of results along with the search results. For example, if someeone filters on category of "Shoes", and location of TX, some of the other filters are going to be restricted based on the previous filter.

Comment: Lackluster performance is in the DB Proc that I'm calling. It can take four or five seconds to execute. I don't return all 800,000 results. I just return 10 results, using rownum in the inner query and using an outer query to pull out rows X through Y.

Comment: Then the next question is where's the bottle neck within the explain plan and what can be done to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a complex join query causing horrible response times.  I was able to solve it via using Lucene.NET.  It's a .NET implementation of the Lucene search index.  Basically, you build indexes on data fields (your categories) and then you can search via those categories and return thousands of rows very quickly.  Basically, it takes the join operation out of the equation because it already knows, via the indexes, which records fit your criteria.

The following is a very good article on Lucene.NET.  I highly recommend it.  It took a search result that was taking 20 seconds using standard joins and reduced the response time to less than a second.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net

Also, feel free to ping me if you have specific Lucene.NET implmenetation questions.  I just got through a lot of research/learning in order to implement it properly on my site, so if you have specific questions on how to make it work I may be able to help with that as well.

Comment: Great. I'm taking a look at this.

Comment: So I'm finally getting back to this. You suggestion for Lucene.NET led me to Solr, which led me to AmazonCloudSearch, which we're now using with much success. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> "I perform the full query b/c I need to populate the new filters and
>   the number of results along with the search results. For example, if
>   someeone filters on category of "Shoes", and location of TX, some of
>   the other filters are going to be restricted based on the previous
>   filter."

Try executing two queries: One to count all results and one to select the top N. Maybe your bottleneck is copying 800,000 rows to the client. Doing two queries would fix this at the cost of an additional query. The cost is likely to be less than 2x though due to optimizations for few rows and for count-only queries.